# How to unsubscribe from setinterval only when input updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need some help with set interval.

I have 2 fields, 1st is an input for insert milleseconds for interval , and the second one is the count itself.

I need to run counter according to the milleseconds that inserted to the input:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [ms, setMS] = useState(1000);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("Start inteval");
      setCount(count + 1);
    }, ms);

    return () => {
      console.log("Clear interval");
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input value={ms} onChange={(e) => setMS(e.target.value)}></input>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

For now it's working, but the problem is in my return (unsubscribe method).

I need to clear the interval only when the input changed and I need to update the ms for interval.

Some one for best solution pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `ms` as dependency in your `useEffect` and also you need to increase counter by 1 with previous state

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log('Start inteval');
      setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);    // replace with this to update counter correctly
    }, ms);

    return () => {
      console.log('Clear interval');
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, [ms]);   // add dependency here
```

Comment: Hi again @Priyank , The console.log('Start interval') is called every second. How can start the interval only one time?